# Isomorphic Rendering with Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, isomorphic-javascript

As a thought exercise, I've been trying to create a blogging application using Isomorphic React. After some google searching I've come across these three tutorials:

Medium: A Modern Isomorphic stack:
https://medium.com/@MoBinni/a-modern-isomorphic-stack-6609c7c9d057

blog.lunarlogic.org: How to create a universal Reactjs application
http://blog.lunarlogic.io/2015/how-to-create-a-universal-reactjs-application-with-bare-reactjs/

One part that I'm confused in particular is with how the `html-webpack-plugin` works on the server side.

Both of these tutorials have templates that look like:

```html
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<%- reactOutput %>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I try to run this template through webpack, I get errors that `reactOutput` is undefined.

On a pure client-side app, I would use `html-webpack-plugin` to generate my `index.html` file to be served to the clients. This generation would make it easier for me because I have different configurations in webpack for dev and production. (Common chunks and all of that)

Do I even need to consider that when talking about server side rendering? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think `html-webpack-plugin` figures in the equation, except to pre-generate the template.
Once you have the template content you provide it to the renderer along with the value of `reactOutput`.

You make [a call like shown here in line 42 to grab the rendered content](http://blog.lunarlogic.io/2015/how-to-create-a-universal-reactjs-application-with-bare-reactjs/#gist27656158):

```
var reactOutput = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps} />);
```

Then you will be giving this var along with the template. [In the tutorial they use ejs for templating](http://blog.lunarlogic.io/2015/how-to-create-a-universal-reactjs-application-with-bare-reactjs/#gist27656839) though you can plug in your own:

```
res.render('index', {
    reactOutput: reactOutput)
});
```

Comment: I get what you're saying to use the output from `html-webpack-plugin` as a template that gets served from the server using `res.render` or `res.send`, but what about the errors I get from `<%- reactOutput %>` not being defined?

I guess one way I could get around that is to read in the whole file as a string and then replace the template code, but how would that work?

Comment: That is exactly how server side rendering works. With ReactDOMServer you render the application in memory, then serve it back to the client. There is still a gap you need to cover, "how do I get the string in memory into the template?" The tutorial you linked shows how to do that using `ejs` for templating. This one is closer to the templating setup you have: http://bitdrift.com/post/2376383378/using-mustache-templates-in-express

Comment: I ended up using `fs.readFileSync` to read the template and `string.replace` to inject the server-side react into the template. Probably not the best approach, but seemed to work.